# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Classes'

Tags: python, dataframe, attributes, data-science, read.csv

Here is a sample of my data:

```
    day month  year Temperature  RH  ...    DC  ISI   BUI  FWI    Classes  
0     1     6  2012          29  57  ...   7.6  1.3   3.4  0.5   not fire   
1     2     6  2012          29  61  ...   7.6    1   3.9  0.4   not fire   
2     3     6  2012          26  82  ...   7.1  0.3   2.7  0.1   not fire   
3     4     6  2012          25  89  ...   6.9    0   1.7    0   not fire   
4     5     6  2012          27  77  ...  14.2  1.2   3.9  0.5   not fire   
..   ..   ...   ...         ...  ..  ...   ...  ...   ...  ...        ...
242  26     9  2012          30  65  ...  44.5  4.5  16.9  6.5       fire   
243  27     9  2012          28  87  ...     8  0.1   6.2    0   not fire   
244  28     9  2012          27  87  ...   7.9  0.4   3.4  0.2   not fire
```

This is my code to plot a scatter graph showing which temperature causes fire:

```py
# Importing libraries
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load the data
# Variable forest is to reps dataframe.
forest = pd.read_csv('ForestFireUp.csv')
print(">>>>>DATA>>>>>")
display(forest)

# Basic information
print(">>>>>INFO>>>>>")
forest.info()
forest.replace(np.nan, '0', inplace = True)
forest.isnull().sum()

# Describe the data
print(">>>>>DESCRIBE>>>>>")
print(forest.describe())

# drop duplicate data

print(">>>>>SUBSETS>>>>>")
temp_data = forest[['Temperature']]
print(temp_data)
print(temp_data.describe())

tempUnique = forest['Temperature'].unique()
tempCount = forest['Temperature'].count()
print(tempUnique)
print(tempCount)

cat_data= forest.Classes.value_counts(normalize = True)
class_data =['not fire', 'fire']
print(cat_data)
y = class_data
x = temp_data
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.ylabel("Classes")
plt.xlabel("Temperature")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `forest['Classes']`?

Comment: Take a look at `forest.dtypes`, and at the .CSV. Are you _sure_ the column name is `'Classes'`, and not for example `'Classes '` or `' Classes'` ?

Comment: Thank you it was 'Classes ' in the .CSV file.